# Is there a way to view the vanilla JavaScript equivalent of a jQuery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, frontend

I'm curious to find out if there are any tools or methods to view the vanilla JS equivalent of a particular jQuery method?

I'm just poking around jQuery and curious to see how these methods work under the hood.

Thanks!

Comment: The non-minified jquery.js file is available for download, so you can see how it works. Or [James Padolsey's jQuery source viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/) is pretty cool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your browser's debugging tools (or even a simple text editor) should do the trick. The "vanilla JS" equivalent of a jQuery method is the jQuery method implementation. It's written in "vanilla JS". You will probably want to look at the [debug version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js) (i.e. non-minified) for readability.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew that my debugger did that. Much appreciated Spender.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of web sites with searchable jQuery source:

- [jQuery Deconstructed](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/deconstructed/jquery/)
- [jQuery Source Viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=)